# Compare map values with clojure

Tags: clojure

I need to filter a map, but the filter should compare the value with the previous one and the filtered map should have just values that has diferent signal of the previous.

Here is a example:

```
Map to filter: {:key1 100 :key2 10 :key3 -20 :key4 -10 :key5 10}
Return: {:key3 -20 :key5 10}
```

Any sugestion of how can I do this?

Comment: The question might be better if you used a sorted-map rather than a straight map, so `(sorted-map :key1 100 :key2 10 :key3 -20 :key4 -10 :key5 10)`. Then the concept of *previous* would make sense.

Comment: Its my understanding that small (fewer than 8 entry) map literals are all sorted. So in this particular example its fine, but for larger examples, its probably not.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, as in the real program this keys will be dates, I can create a sorted map of them.

Comment: @user12341234 This is not correct -- 0 to 8 k/v entries in a map literal will default to an ArrayMap, and a `seq` view will show the order in which they were inserted, **not** sorted order. Creating or assoc'ing to a map once it reaches this limit will implicitly convert it to a HashMap, where insertion order is no longer guaranteed (and very unlikely). All of these are implementation details which should not be relied upon, just giving it for clarity.  But the point is: sort of any kind **must be made explicit**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use [partition-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-by) which chunks up a sequence based on when the sequence changes value. We can tell `partition-by` to look at the "signum" of the values, and then only take the first result in each chunk.

```
(->> {:key1 100 :key2 10 :key3 -20 :key4 -10 :key5 10}
     (partition-by #(Integer/signum (val %)))
     rest
     (map first))

=> ([:key3 -20] [:key5 10])
```

Comment: The keys in a map are not ordered so you need to define what the 'next' key is supposed to be for this to work reliably.

Comment: While I agree with your comment, I think that's an issue with the specification of the question, rather than my answer.

Comment: Would suggest using `(into (sorted-map) ...)` for both your first line, to make it actually sorted, and also adding after the `(map first)` to achieve the map result that the OP mentioned.

Comment: @user12341234 A good answer should figure out what the question is actually asking, rather than answering an underspecified question.

Comment: @Josh Actually it would be wrong for this function to sort the map. Rather, it should demand a sorted map as input, and then end with `(into (empty the-input) ...)` to produce a map with the same sorting rules as the one that was input, rather than always using the default sorting rules. Or, more probably, it should work on a sequence of key/value pairs instead of a map at all, since this isn't really a map-oriented problem.

Comment: @amalloy but this is just an expression, not a function, so there are no inputs. I was suggesting a way to make this particular example work to show the intent. But your point is well taken, particularly the call to `empty`.